# Intra-RDS Database communications setup on common VPC and security groups

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, database-replication, aws-security-group

I have a production database plus a new database that I stood up on AWS. Both are Postgres. I wanted to use replication to copy a table from production into the new database. I did an `nslookup` to get the public IP of the new database and added it into the incoming rules for the security groups. After getting all the postgres commands in, I can replicate just fine.

I understand that the RDS IP addresses are not static. The incoming rule takes an IP address as an input so it is conceivable that the rule breaks if the IP address changes. What is the correct method for adding a database to the security group so that the rule can withstand an IP address change?

Comment: Are they in the same VPC, or at least peered VPCs?

Comment: They are in the same VPC.

Comment: I'm not sure why the public IP address is working at all then, it should be using the private IP. You should be creating an inbound rule that references the security group ID of the first database, instead of the IP address.

Comment: I share the security groups between databases. Should I be creating a distinct security group for the new database and add that as an "incoming" rule for the prod?

Comment: A security group can reference itself in rules. Although best practice is to separate them out.

Comment: I found the row where the security group it is referring to itself. In your experience do you add an inbound rule in this case or do you just do nothing?

Comment: Your last question is unclear. Are you saying it already has an inbound rule referencing itself? If so why would you add the same rule again? Also, that's probably the reason it is currently working.

Comment: Yes, the security group has a rule where it references itself. If I remove the direct IP though, it stops working. I'm going to separate them out like you suggested.

Comment: It sounds like your databases are publicly accessible and the traffic is leaving the VPC to go out over the Internet.

Comment: @MarkB, yeah, you're right. They are both publicly accessible. I split the security groups. Prod has SG-A and new has SG-B. SG-A has an inbound rule for SG-B. With postgres when I try to manipulate the subscription and drop it, it says it can't find the address host "prod.db.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (34.236.XX.XX). What is of interest is this IP. It doesn't look like an internal AWS IP but rather a public one. Are there internal names that can be used instead of the endpoint names?

Comment: Unfortunately if you have the databases set to publicly accessible they are going to try to talk to each other over the Internet and there isn't a private IP endpoint you can use.